# How to make a response not show a reply message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i created a command that sends a embed with discord.py modals but I ran into a thing that bothered me. How do I send a interaction twice without responding to the first interaction? For example this is what I want it to look like:  [image]

I tried to do interaction.followup.send but that didnt work

Comment: You can use `interaction.channel.send()`

Comment: @Jabro I don't think that's true. I'm pretty sure you can use followup after any type of response

Comment: You only need to use defer if you want it to show "bot is thinking" for up to 15 minutes before sending a message. If you send a message as a response instead, that works too.
As far as interaction.channel.send, it appears they have done that since it does not show as a reply to the first response, but it's not recommended for bots in guilds you don't control since it requires the bot to have permissions to send messages, which is separate from app commands permissions.

Answer (score 1):

In the image you showed it seems they have done something such as the following. This is not the best solution as it requires send messages permissions and not just application commands permissions.

```py
await interaction.response.send_message("message A", ephemeral=True)
await interaction.channel.send("message B")
```

[image]

I would recommend instead to use followup:

```py
await interaction.response.send_message("message A", ephemeral=True)
await interaction.followup.send("message B")
```

[image]